# How to redirect uri to suburi with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I've read up on how to use config.action_controller.relative_url_root to set a sub uri in rails and I plan to set my site to www.mydomain.com/mysub_uri.

What I would like thought is for www.mydomain.com to redirect automatically to www.mydoamin.com/mysub_uri.

How do I go about doing this? I am using rails, apache, and phusion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an Apache rewrite (completely independent of Rails).  Check the docs here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html